# vega .on event handler

Tags: javascript, vega

```
.on("mouseover", function(event, item) {
  // invoke hover properties on cousin one hop forward in scenegraph
  view.update({
    props: "hover",
   items: item.cousin(1)
  });
});
```

this code i got from this link :

https://github.com/trifacta/vega/blob/master/examples/interact/index.html

I did not understand what is

```
items: item.cousin(1);
```

I'm using it to plot a graph on vega.

Comment: You don't understand the syntax, or you don't know what the `.cousin()` method does? Your question is unclear. Give a complete description of the issue.

Comment: @cookiemonster actually both. im not understanding the syntax and i dont know whats that .cousin() method does.

Comment: If you don't understand the syntax, then you need to start with reading some beginner's material. If you don't understand what `.cousin()` does, then you should read the documentation.

Comment: I've poked around the documentation and haven't found anything useful. From google groups: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/vega-js/cBvB0YzdJ7U and in the source code: https://github.com/trifacta/vega/blob/e8013b855ef8331d1a07b9ef266cc8fc2738e436/src/scene/Item.js#l13 I feel like I sort of ge tthe gist, but I would appreciate some clearer documentation (if it exists). I'd also be interested to learn more about the `sibling` function which appears to be related. But I don't think it's fair to fault OP for not reading documentation that appears to not exist.

Comment: thank you. i understood what that cousin function is. it is internal stuff

Comment: Note that the trifacta/vega is quite old. Please upgrade to vega/vega.